Why is my C# SMTP Email code failing in Visual Studio Code
I have a suspicion that the problem I am having has something to do with Visual Studio Code rather than with the C# code itself.  I have recently configured my Visual Studio Code IDE to compile and build a C# (Command Line Console App) project and solution.  But the moment I add meaningful code, it fales to properly recognize simple classes.  Here is the simple test code I am trying:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.WebSockets;

namespace SendEmailWIthGoogleSMTP
{
    class Program
    {
        string fromMail ="REDACTED@gmail.com";
        string password ="REDACTED";

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(fromMail);
        message.Subject = "Test Subjecting";
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(REDACTED@gmail.com);
        message.Body ="This is a test";
        message.IsBodyHtml= false;

    }
}

But here is the problem.  It complains that 'message' is not defined albeit it does not complain after I define it.  I know that sounds confusing, so here is the screen shot.


Your code is not in a method.

Your code contains several issues that prevent it from even compiling

Missing Main method
Line 17: REDACTED@gmail.com is not a string
Line 17: missing a closing )

This compiles:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.WebSockets;

namespace SendEmailWithGoogleSMTP
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string fromMail = "REDACTED@gmail.com";
      string password = "REDACTED";

      MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
      message.From = new MailAddress(fromMail);
      message.Subject = "Test Subjecting";
      message.To.Add(new MailAddress("REDACTED@gmail.com"));
      message.Body = "This is a test";
      message.IsBodyHtml = false;
    }
  }
}


Your code causes an issue because the initialization of MailMessage and its properties occurs directly within the class scope, which is not allowed. Instead, this should be done within a method, like Main() or another function.
Class-level statements in C# can only declare fields and methods.

Your code looks like it has been written using top level statements but inside a class and should be:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.WebSockets;

string fromMail ="REDACTED@gmail.com";
string password ="REDACTED";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(fromMail);
message.Subject = "Test Subjecting";
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(REDACTED@gmail.com);
message.Body ="This is a test";
message.IsBodyHtml= false;

It also looks like you've introduced a typo during redaction. The line below is missing double quotes around the email address and a closing parenthesis:
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(REDACTED@gmail.com);

Should be:
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("REDACTED@gmail.com"));

